# Hierarchical partitioning for GAM model?

Tags: feature-selection, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, deviance

I am fitting a gam model with multiple environmental factors as predictors (actual evapotranspiration, climate water deficit, wind speed, etc).

My goal is to understand how each one of them contribute in explaining the variance of the response variable. Therefore, I am trying to calculate individual contributions of each predictor towards total deviance explained. Hierarchical partitioning allows to quantify the individual contribution of predictors to the full model, as explained in detail [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2684366.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A7762aa06e28608296772cd941a9be8ca&ab_segments=&origin=&initiator=&acceptTC=1).

Doing this manually would be very time consuming as I have many predictors (11) and I would have to build many variants of the model. I have found that hier.part and glmm.hp functions do hierarchical partitioning in R. However, it seems that these functions are made for GLM and not GAM. Is there a way to do hierarchical partitoning for GAMs in R?

Or is there another way to evaluate individual effect of predictors on the response variable?
I have also checked `gam.scope` and `step.Gam` but I am not sure how to use them properly.